# Objective C - Rotate bounds of section header in UICollectionView

Tags: objective-c, rotation, uicollectionview, drawrect

I'm sure there's a very, very simple solution here but I just can't seem to figure it out. I have a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView with section headers. I want the section header text to be written vertically as so:

[image: Section headers]

I know it has something to do with rotating the context, but despite reading through the documentation and reading similar posts on here, I can't seem to quite grasp this one. This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)drawTitle
{
    CGRect titleRect = self.bounds;

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName: DEFAULT_FONT size: self.bounds.size.width * FONT_WIDTH_FACTOR];

    NSAttributedString *cellText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: self.title attributes: @{ NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle, NSFontAttributeName : cellFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }];

    [cellText drawInRect: titleRect];

    // Rotation code???
}
```

I'd really appreciate the help on this, as simple as I'm sure it is. I'm just clearly missing something here. Thank you very much, in advance.

Comment: (Off-topic) That font is too heavy in decorations and serif to be used in such a small font size, it doesn't help readability in any way. Go with a non-serif, tall x-height font, or heavier weight (or any combination of the previous).

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Transforms/Transforms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a diagram of your graphics context, if you draw the text the way you're doing now:

[image: diagram 1]

We need to do two things.  We need to rotate the coordinate system so that the text is drawn vertically, and we need to move the coordinate system (or the text rectangle) so that the rotated text rectangle exactly overlaps the (unrotated) `self.bounds` rectangle.

We can't transform the coordinate system at all using UIKit functions.  We have to go down to the Core Graphics (aka Quartz) level.   So first, we get a reference to the graphics context and save its state:

```
CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(gc); {
```

Now we can transform the coordinate system.  First we'll “translate” (move) the origin to the bottom left corner of the bounds rectangle:

```
    CGContextTranslateCTM(gc, 0, titleRect.size.height);
```

At this point, if we draw the string, the graphics context will look like this:

[image: diagram 2]

So now we'll rotate the coordinate system by a right angle:

```
    CGContextRotateCTM(gc, -M_PI_2);
```

It's possible I have the sign of the angle wrong.  If nothing shows up, try removing the `-` sign.

Now if we draw the string, the graphics context will look like this:

[image: diagram 3]

Note that in the rectangle we pass to `drawInRect:`, the `width` is always a distance along the x axis, and now the x axis is vertical.  So we want the text rectangle to be as wide as the view's height, and we want the text rectangle to be as tall as the view's width.  Thus:

```
    [cellText drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleRect.size.height, titleRect.size.width)];
```

And we're all done, so we restore the graphics context's state:

```
} CGContextRestoreGState(gc);
```

All together:

```
CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(gc); {
    CGContextTranslateCTM(gc, 0, titleRect.size.height);
    CGContextRotateCTM(gc, -M_PI_2);
    [cellText drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, titleRect.size.height, titleRect.size.width)];
} CGContextRestoreGState(gc);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rob! This was extremely helpful! There's one thing I can't seem to figure out -- is there any reason why the text wouldn't be center aligning in this rect given the code I posted initially? For some reason it seems to remain left-aligned.

Comment: I don't know why it's not centered.

Answer (score 0):

This is not another answer to the question but rather just a follow-up to rob mayoff's already excellent answer.

I was also having trouble with the text not being centered after the rotation. I came up with the following "fix"--eh, let's call it what it is, a kludge--to get the text centered.

I am by no means an iPhone programming expert, and there are undoubtedly better ways of doing this, but this worked for me.

```
if (...scrolling is horizontal...) {
    // Rotate the text so it runs vertically.
    CGAffineTransform rotateItem = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
    header.label.transform = rotateItem;

    // After rotating the label the text is always left-justified,
    // i.e. it appears at the bottom of the screen. Do some calculations
    // to get the title space-padded so it appears roughly centered.

    // Calculate the size of the label.
    float sizeOfLabel = [header.label.text sizeWithFont:header.label.font].width;

    // Calculate where the label should start if it is to appear centered.
    float centeredLabelStartPosition = (header.frame.size.height - sizeOfLabel) / 2.0;

    // Calculate the size of a space character.
    float sizeOfSpaceChar = [@" " sizeWithFont:header.label.font].width;

    // Calculate how many leading space characters are needed to appear before the label
    // so that the label appears centered. (The +1 is because I like it shifted
    // ever-so-slightly toward the top of the screen, rather than true center.)
    int numberOfLeadingSpaces = roundf(centeredLabelStartPosition / sizeOfSpaceChar) + 1;

    // Create the label with leading space padding to get it centered.
    header.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%*s%@", numberOfLeadingSpaces, "", header.label.text];
} else {
    // For vertical scrolling, turn off the rotation (which might have been left on
    // if this label was used previously).
    header.label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```

Important note: When a user rotates the iPhone orientation between horizontal and vertical, iOS doesn't call collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath: to redraw section headers. So, the headers aren't automatically re-centered on rotation.

---

Here's an even simpler way to get the header text centered... if you're willing to turn off "autolayout" for your app. This also has the benefit that headers can be automatically re-centered on rotation. In the storyboard you'll have to set up your header to expand horizontally (or do it programmatically).

```
if (...scrolling is horizontal...) {
    // Rotate the text so it runs vertically.
    header.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
    // Center the text after rotation.
    header.label.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, header.frame.size.width, header.frame.size.height);
    header.label.center = CGPointMake(header.frame.size.width/2, header.frame.size.height/2);
} else {
    // For vertical scrolling, turn off the rotation (which might have been left on
    // if this label was used previously).
    header.label.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
}
```